# how do I install curl from source, including updating the libcurl version?

Tags: linux, installation, curl, apt

I am working on a distro of linux that doesn't have the version of curl I need supported via apt-get. The latest I can get through apt-get is 7.52.1 and I want the latest (7.65.1). So, I've followed the instructions on the curl website to [build and install curl from source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html), adjusting the prefix so that curl is built in my own folder rather than `/usr/local/`. When I go into that folder, `~/curl_install/bin`, and try to run curl I get the following issue:

```bsh
$./curl --version
curl 7.64.1 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
./curl: symbol lookup error: ./curl: undefined symbol: curl_mime_free
```

Curl is now at the latest version, but libcurl is not. How can I update libcurl to be in parity with curl?

Comment: I would guess, that you probably already compiled it when you built curl.  You just need to get the library into your library path.  Possibly have to manipulate LD_LIBRARY_PATH or something.

Comment: ah. that's it. What does LD_LIBRARY_PATH do?